# Python will not print even test strings after calling a join. Executes with code 0 though

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I am writing some Python code to rename some files. In doing so, I have ran across a peculiar error. When I try to print anything after my join, nothing will print. Not even `print 'test'`.

What could be causing this?
Here is the code :

```
       ... #finding all images in a .html
       for t in soup.find_all('img'):                    # Note: soup exists outside of with
            try:
                old_src = t['src']                        # Access src attribute
                image = os.path.split(old_src)[1]         # Get file name
                #print 'image => ' + image

                relpath = os.path.relpath(root, do)       # Get relative path from do to root
                folders = relpath.strip('\\').split('\\') # Remove outer slashes, split on folder separator
                #BELOW LINE CAUSES PROBLEM
                new_src = '_'.join(folders.append(str(image))) # Join folders and image by underscore
                print t['src'] #prints nothing
                print 'test' #prints nothing
                t['src'] = new_src                        # Modify src attribute
            except:                                       # Do nothing if tag does not have src attribute
                pass
```

It confuses me that nothing prints below this line, as it clearly reaches the end of execution...it will not do anything after this line though as far as I can see. Execution stops completely.

Can anyone see any issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the `join` line is even being reached in the first place?  If you put a `print` before the `join`, does that show up?

Comment: @jwodder It does, trying to print any and all values (including all variables) before the join works perfectly. It's only afterwards there's an issue. I've tested it a lot :)

Comment: Another example of [the most diabolical Python antipattern](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`folders.append(str(image))` returns nothing (`None`), so the program would raise an exception and skip your `print` statements.

You can solve it simply by replacing your `new_src = '_'.join(folders.append(str(image)))` with two following lines:

```
folders.append(str(image))
new_src = '_'.join(folders)
```

If you catch exception by `except Exception as e:` and `print e`, you will see the TypeError error message, because it's same as doing `'_'.join(None)` by executing `'_'.join(folders.append(str(image)))`

Comment: Ah, thank you, never would have figured this out! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `folders` is a normal `list`, `folders.append` returns `None`, but `str.join` expects an iterable as its argument, so it raises a `TypeError` ... which is then caught and ignored by your `except: pass`, after which execution continues with the next `t in soup.find_all('img')`, and so the `print`s are never reached.